# How to circumvent dlopen() caching?

Tags: c, linker, posix, dlopen

According to its [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), `dlopen()` will not load the same library twice:

> If the **same shared object** is loaded again with dlopen(), the same
>   object handle is returned.  The dynamic linker maintains reference
>   counts for object handles, so a dynamically loaded shared object is
>   not deallocated until dlclose() has been called on it as many times
>   as dlopen() has succeeded on it.  Any initialization returns (see
>   below) are called just once.  However, a subsequent dlopen() call
>   that loads the same shared object with RTLD_NOW may force symbol
>   resolution for a shared object earlier loaded with RTLD_LAZY.

(emphasis mine).

But what actually determines the identity of shared objects? I tried to look into the code, but did not come very far. Is it:

- some form of normalized path name (e.g. realpath?)
- the inode ?
- the contents of the libray?

I am pretty sure that I can rule out this last point, since an actual filesystem copy yields two different handles.

To explain the motivation behind this question: I am working with some code that has static global variables. I need multiple instances of that code to run in a thread-safe manner. My current approach is to compile and link said code into a dynamic library and load that library multiple times. With some linker magic, it appears to create several copies of the globals and resolve access in each library to its own copies. The only problem is that my prototype copies the generated library n times for n concurrent uses. This is not only somewhat ugly but I also suspect that it might break on a different platform.

So what is the exact behaviour of `dlopen()` according to the POSIX standard?

**edit:** Because it came up in a comment and an answer, no refactoring the code is definitely not an option. It would involve months or even years of work and potentially sacrifice all benefits of using the code in the first place. There **exists** an ongoing research project that might solve this problem in a much cleaner way, but it is actual research and might fail. I need a solution now.

**edit2:** Because people still seem to not believe the usecase is actually valid. I am working on a pure functional language, that shall be embedded into a larger C/C++ application. Because I need a prototype with a garbage collector, a proven typechecker, and reasonable performance ASAP, I used OCaml as intermediate code. Right now, I am compiling a source module into an OCaml module, link the generated object code (including startup etc.) into a shared library **with the OCaml runtime** and dlopen() **that** shared library. Every .so has its own copy of the runtime, including several global variabels (e.g. the pointer to the young generation) and that is, or rather should be, totally fine. The library exposes exactly two functions: An initializer and a single export that does whatever the original module is intended to do. No symbols of the OCaml runtime are exported/shared. when I load the library, its internal symbols are relocated as expected, the only issue I have right now is that I actually need to copy the .so file for each instance of the job at runtime.

Regarding thread-local-storage: That is actually an interesting idea, as the modification to the runtime is indeed rather simple. But the problem is the machine code generated by the OCaml compiler, as it cannot emit loading instructions for tls symbols (yet?).

Comment: `dlopen()` will not solve your problem of a fundamentally broken library ... If you can compile the code in question yourself, you should better fix it to be thread-safe :o

Comment: If the library is not thread-aware, you can at least replace static storage duration data with thread local data. This is a completely mechanical task that shouldn't require research effort or months to complete.

Comment: That might be a worthwhile experiment. But for that task, I'd need to know two things: 1. how to shared libraries deal with thread local storage and how do ELF object files declare them?

Comment: TLS and shared libraries are orthogonal. You should't care about ELF, you declare your data as TLS in the C source code and rebuild.

Comment: Except that some part of that code is not C, but (generated) X86 assembly.

Comment: How could you possibly verify that any kludge you force into place is actually working?  Just.  Don't.

Comment: No, you cannot mechanically modify assembly code to use TLS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

POSIX says:

> Only a single copy of an object file is brought into the address space, even if dlopen() is invoked multiple times in reference to the file, and even if different pathnames are used to reference the file.

So the answer is "inode". Copying the library file "should work", but hard links won't. Except. Since they will expose the same global symbols and when that happens all (portability) bets are off. You're in the middle of weakly defined behavior that has evolved through bug fixes rather than good design.

Don't dig deeper when you're in a hole. The approach to add additional horrible hacks to make a fundamentally broken library work just leads to additional breakage. Just spend a few hours to fix the library to not use globals instead of spending days to hack around dynamic linking (which will be unportable at best).

Comment: RTLD_LOCAL should take care of global symbols. Though I agree that getting rid of global/static data is the way to go.

Comment: So, what's the actual POSIX definition of "object file"?  Just copying it to a different file with a different inode may not be sufficient.  After all, it's still the same symbols.

Comment: @AndrewHenle POSIX is often vague on purpose because different systems behave differently. The "even if different pathnames" bit there implies that the deduplication will most likely happen on whatever `stat` returns. Although I do know that this is somewhere between wishful thinking  and bullshit because the ld.so I worked in dosen't do any deduplication on anything if the object loaded is with a path name (`dlopen` was standardized long after I worked in that code, I suspect the POSIX process in this case was "document glibc, screw everyone else").

Comment: @AndrewHenle POSIX says "File: an object that can be written to, or read from, or both". When you write to one file and the other stays intact, they are different files.

Comment: @n.m. That doesn't resolve whether object files with identical contents can in fact be loaded into a process's memory in any way so the multiple copies do not interfere with each other.

Comment: @AndrewHenle in my universe I can guarantee that a copy of a file is not the same object as the original file. Can't vouch about yours though.

Comment: @n.m. Don't be deliberately dense.  Loading an object file that has the exact same contents as another file isn't guaranteed to work just because the two identical copies happen to be independent.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have no idea where you are getting this from. Same ffile is same file. Different files are different files. POSIX says that the **same object file** will not be loaded twice. It does not say that **different files** with the same content will not be loaded twice. I have no reason to believe the latter possibility merits a consideration.

Comment: @n.m. It's not an unreasonable consideration. On systems with bad relocations it might not be possible. It wasn't that long ago (in my head at least, although it has been several decades) when there were systems with shared libraries that weren't position independent.

Comment: @n.m. In fact, now that I think of it, it wasn't that long ago (pre-Vista) that Windows required all shared libraries to be prelinked at fixed addresses. If this process was done inside a file (don't know how Windows did this, but it's not an unreasonable implementation), two raw copies of a shared library file could conflict.

Comment: @n.m. And even if two or more identical copies of an object file can be loaded into a process's memory, that doesn't mean the multiple copies can coexist.  The code within the object file can do things that conflict with the actions of other copies.  For example, a singleton lock, or expecting exclusive access to some resource.  And that's all assuming every bit of code in the process can distinguish between copy A of `someSymbol` and copy B of `someSymbol`. There's a lot more to deal with than just snarkily relying on "different filename == different file in my universe".

Comment: @Art The entire misunderstanding is about what Posix considers "the same file", not about addresses or relocations or anything like that. Of course you can have conflicts when you prelink at fixed addresses, whether or not your files have different contents. When you try to dlopen **the same object file** twice, you get a success and the reference count is bumped. When you dlopen **two different files** with conflicting relocations, you get an error. We're not ever mentioned the latter case. We just can't seem to agree what exactly "the same file" is.

Comment: @AndrewHenle We seem to be talking about entirely different things and not understanding each other. I don't think the comments section is an appropriate place to resolve this. You also seem to ascribe things to me that I have never said or implied, like different filenames == different files, which is obviously false. I have no idea how you have ever arrived at that.