# How to clear internal cache of libloading in Rust

Tags: dynamic, rust

As the title says. There seems to be a internal cache in libloading for libaries with the same path. How would I clear it or drop an item from it.

The following `mwe`.

```
use libloading::{Library, Symbol};
use std::process::Command;

fn write(i: i64) {
    std::fs::write("source.rs", format!("
#[no_mangle]
pub extern \"C\" fn fun() {{
    println!(\"{}\");
}}", i)).expect("write error");
}

fn compile() {
    Command::new("rustc")
        .arg("--crate-type")
        .arg("cdylib")
        .arg("source.rs")
        .arg("-o")
        .arg("binary.o")
        .output()
        .expect("compile error");
}

fn run() {
    let lib = Library::new("./binary.o").unwrap();

    unsafe {
        lib.get::<Symbol<unsafe extern "C" fn()>>(b"fun").unwrap()()
    }
}

fn main() {
    for i in 0..10 {
        write(i);
        compile();
        run();
    }
}
```

returns

```
0
0
0
...
```

I would however like

```
0
1
2
...
```

Comment: Does [“How to circumvent dlopen() caching?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954861/how-to-circumvent-dlopen-caching) answer your question?

Comment: @mcarton. Hm, it helps, but I'm not quite there yet. The inode doesn't seem to change with each call of compile. So maybe I can force a new inode to get the result. But this looks quite dirty if you ask me.

Comment: But calling rustc from within your program to compile dynamically built Rust code and using `libloading` to load it is not "quite dirty"?

Comment: @mcarton. That it would be. I only did this to shorten the `mwe`.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up reinventing the wheel. In case anybody will stumble upon the same issue:

```
use libc;

use std::ffi::CStr;
use std::mem::transmute;

pub struct SharedLib {
    handle: *mut libc::c_void,
}

impl SharedLib {
    pub fn new(path: &str) -> Self {
        let path = CStr::from_bytes_with_nul(path.as_bytes()).unwrap();
        let handle = unsafe { libc::dlopen(path.as_ptr(), libc::RTLD_NOW) };

        SharedLib {
            handle: handle,
        }
    }

    pub fn run<T>(&self, name: &str) -> T {
        if self.handle.is_null() {
            panic!("error");
        }

        let name = CStr::from_bytes_with_nul(name.as_bytes()).unwrap();
        unsafe {
            let ptr = libc::dlsym(self.handle, name.as_ptr());
            transmute::<_, fn() -> T>(ptr)()
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for SharedLib {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            libc::dlclose(self.handle);
        }
    }
}
```